# Swift's Calendar.enumerateDates gives incorrect result when starting on February

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I am experiencing very strange results when using Swift's Calendar.enumerateDates.

It works as expected except when starting from dates in February.

Consider the following code:

```
    let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: 2017, month: 2, day: 2)
    var testDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)

    var firstOfMonth = DateComponents(day: 1)
    Calendar.current.enumerateDates(startingAfter: testDate!, matching: firstOfMonth, matchingPolicy: .strict, direction: .forward) { (matchedDate, match, stop) in
        let wrongResult = matchedDate!
        stop = true
    }
```

In the code above, I would expect `wrongResult` to be March 1, 2017 but I get February 1, 2020...

Am I doing something wrong or I have found a bug?

Comment: That is really strange. If you use day 2 it would return March 2, 2017 as expected. Even stranger is that if you start from `DateComponents(year: 2017, month: 2, day: 1)` it would work as expected also.

Comment: Miguel, I think you've found a [bug](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Ok, I reported a bug. I will update if I get new info!

Comment: @miguelSantirso have you heard from Apple regarding your feedback? I’m also seeing strange results when I need to use the nextDate or enumerateDates methods