# Calendar.nextDate() is acting really weird when using .backward for direction. Only for the last day of the month

Tags: ios, swift, macos, calendar, swift4

In my app I need to get the previous 4am, not the 4am of the current date.
For example:

- if it's `March 05, 10:00 am` then I should expect to get back: `March 05, 4:00 am`
- if it's `March 05, 02:00 am` then I should expect to get back: `March 04, 4:00 am`

To achieve that I'm using `Calendar.nextDate`. It works well for everyday of the month except the last day of each month.

#### This is an example of the happy path, where it works as expected:

```swift
let components = DateComponents(hour: 4, minute: 0, second: 0)

let date =  Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2018,
                                                       month: 03, 
                                                       day: 05, 
                                                       hour: 13, 
                                                       minute: 25, 
                                                       second: 0))!
let result = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: date, 
                                       matching: components,
                                       matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                                       direction: .backward)
```

Output:

```
date = "Mar 5, 2018 at 1:25 PM"
result = "Mar 5, 2018 at 4:00 AM"
```

#### This is an example of the dark sad path, where it does **NOT** act as expected:

```swift
let components = DateComponents(hour: 4, minute: 0, second: 0)

let date =  Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2018,
                                                       month: 03, 
                                                       day: 31, 
                                                       hour: 13, 
                                                       minute: 25, 
                                                       second: 0))!
let result = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: date, 
                                       matching: components,
                                       matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                                       direction: .backward)
```

Output:

```
date = "Mar 31, 2018 at 1:25 PM"
result = "Mar 30, 2018 at 4:00 AM"
// it should give me this instead: "Mar 31, 2018 at 4:00 AM"
```

Any idea why this is happening? is it a bug in Apple's code, should I report it? or am I using this wrong?
If it's an Apple bug, is there another way of achieving what I need in the meantime?

### Update:

After looking at some Swift source code, I noticed that the issue is not with the `Calendar.nextDate()` function specifically. `nextDate()` uses `Calendar.enumerateDates()` and that's where the real issue is. I couldn't find the source code for that function though. 
This is the same bug using `Calendar.enumerateDates()`:

```swift
let components = DateComponents(hour: 4, minute: 0, second: 0)

let date =  Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2018,
                                                       month: 03, 
                                                       day: 31, 
                                                       hour: 13, 
                                                       minute: 25, 
                                                       second: 0))!

Calendar.current.enumerateDates(startingAfter: inputDate,
                                matching: components, 
                                matchingPolicy: .nextTime, 
                                direction: .backward) { (date, exactMatch, stop) in
    let result = date
    // result = "Mar 30, 2018 at 4:00 AM"
    stop = true
}
```

Also, this is a similar issue: [Swift's Calendar.enumerateDates gives incorrect result when starting on February](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982214/swifts-calendar-enumeratedates-gives-incorrect-result-when-starting-on-february)

Comment: That is strange. For `4:59 AM` you get `4:00 AM` on the same day as result, but for `5:00 AM` you get `4:00 AM` on the day before. I have no idea what is happening here.

Comment: A month end issue?  Using Jan 31, Feb 28, or Apr 30, 2018 at 1:35 PM, also back up to previous day.

Comment: Excellent sleuthing ️‍♀️!

Comment: Very strange. After dealing with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266027/calculate-previous-sunday-when-dst-changed-on-the-previous-sunday I have just discovered that the issue in this question only appears in an iOS playground as well. In a macOS playground this code works as expected.

Comment: @rmaddy it is indeed strange, I thought all SDKs share the same Foundation framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does appear to be a bug that should be reported to Apple. Be sure you include a runnable test app demonstrating the issue. **Note** that this bug only appears in iOS. In macOS (at least a macOS playground), the code works as expected.

In the meantime there is a fairly simple workaround.

Change your code to use `.forward` instead of `.backward`. This will give the next date instead of the previous date. There does not seem to be any bugs going in that direction. Then use:

```
Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, date: result)
```

to get your desired result by going back one day.