# Calculate previous Sunday when DST changed on the previous Sunday

Tags: ios, swift

Today is Tuesday March 13th, 2018. The previous Sunday was March 11th, 2018. My code to calculate the previous Sunday is:

```
// NOTE that this particular code block may return the correct result for you IF your timezone 
// is something other than "America/Chicago". E.g. "America/Belize". Use the longer code 
// block that begins with "var calendar = ..." if you are trying to replicate the issue
Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(),
                          matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1),
                          matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                          repeatedTimePolicy: .first,
                          direction: .backward)!
```

This returns the date of March 4th, not the expected value of March 11th. This is due to a [DST change](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/chicago?year=2018). I've tried every combination of `matchingPolicy` and `repeatedTimePolicy` but it always returns March 4th. Any thoughts on how I could get the calendar to return March 11th?

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Chicago")!
// Tuesday March 13th @ 3:10 PM (America/Chicago)
let today = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1520971846)

let d1 = calendar.nextDate(after: today,
                           matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1),
                           matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                           repeatedTimePolicy: .first,
                           direction: .backward)!

let d2 = calendar.nextDate(after: today,
                           matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1),
                           matchingPolicy: .nextTimePreservingSmallerComponents,
                           repeatedTimePolicy: .first,
                           direction: .backward)!

let d3 = calendar.nextDate(after: today,
                           matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1),
                           matchingPolicy: .previousTimePreservingSmallerComponents,
                           repeatedTimePolicy: .first,
                           direction: .backward)!

let d4 = calendar.nextDate(after: today,
                           matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1),
                           matchingPolicy: .strict,
                           repeatedTimePolicy: .first,
                           direction: .backward)!

let d5 = calendar.nextDate(after: today,
                           matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1),
                           matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                           repeatedTimePolicy: .last,
                           direction: .backward)!

let d6 = calendar.nextDate(after: today,
                           matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1),
                           matchingPolicy: .nextTimePreservingSmallerComponents,
                           repeatedTimePolicy: .last,
                           direction: .backward)!

let d7 = calendar.nextDate(after: today,
                           matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1),
                           matchingPolicy: .previousTimePreservingSmallerComponents,
                           repeatedTimePolicy: .last,
                           direction: .backward)!

let d8 = calendar.nextDate(after: today,
                           matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1),
                           matchingPolicy: .strict,
                           repeatedTimePolicy: .last,
                           direction: .backward)!
```

[Bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=38432865) has been filed per suggestion.

Comment: You should be getting valid results here; DST shouldn't affect being able to find the day (especially with matching policies other than `.strict`). Do you mind please [filing a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com)?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your first bit of code into an Xcode 9.2 playground and it correctly gives me a result of March 11, 2018.

Comment: @rmaddy: That is strange – I can reproduce the issue with above code.

Comment: Btw, here is another recently observed bug with backwards search: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49202865/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR If it helps I ran it in a macOS playground only importing Foundation. And I'm in a timezone in the USA with a locale of en_US.

Comment: I was also able to reproduce the issue in Xcode 9.2 playgrounds.

Comment: @rmaddy Are you in 'America/Chicago' timezone? The first block of code is not an accurate reproduction of the issue because it will use your timezone. I just included that block for a simple version. Could you try pasting the second code block?

Comment: Perhaps the same bug as reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49202865/calendar-nextdate-is-acting-really-weird-when-using-backward-for-direction-o?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Jon I'm in the mountain time zone. I'll be away from the computer for a couple of hours.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. The first code block worked for you because DST is not observed in Mountain Standard Time ('America/Phoenix').

Comment: @Jon I'm not in Arizona (which does not observe DST). The rest of MST does observe DST.

Comment: FYI - I just copied all of the code in your question as-is into a macOS playground from Xcode 9.2 importing just Foundation and every single dX variable shows as March 10, 2018 11pm. I'm also running on macOS 10.12.6 if that makes any difference.

Comment: @MartinR OK, this just got weirder. I just put all of the code into an iOS playground from Xcode 9.2 importing just UIKit and I now see the same issue. It works fine in a macOS playground but gives the wrong answer in an iOS playground.

Comment: That is odd. I'm running macOS 10.13.3, Xcode 9.2. Both iOS playground w/ UIKit and macOS playground w/ Foundation show me wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely an Apple bug, as the comment above says.

There is a **very ugly** workaround by first finding the "next" Sunday, then using that date to find the previous Sunday. I am sure there are some edge cases where this won't work, but maybe it might help you.

```
// Not recommended for production code

var nextSunday = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(),
                                       matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1),
                                       matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                                       repeatedTimePolicy: .first,
                                       direction: .forward)!

var lastSunday = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: nextSunday,
                                       matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1),
                                       matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                                       repeatedTimePolicy: .first,
                                       direction: .backward)!
```

[image]

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution as it is slightly better than what my solution would have been. I did some testing and matching `.forward` correctly accounts for DST. It is just matching `.backward` where there is an issue

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to subtract seven days from "today" and then just search `.forward`. Personally, I won't be searching `.backward` due to this DST issue and due to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49202865/calendar-nextdate-is-acting-really-weird-when-using-backward-for-direction-o?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Chicago")!
// Tuesday March 13th @ 3:10 PM (America/Chicago)
var date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1520971846)
date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: date)!
//or = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: date)!

let lastSunday = calendar.nextDate(after: date,
                           matching: DateComponents(weekday: 1),
                           matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                           repeatedTimePolicy: .first,
                           direction: .forward)!
```

Comment: Why don't you subtract a week instead of minus 7 days?

Comment: @LeoDabus I added syntax for subtracting a week. Do you feel there is a benefit to subtracting a week instead of 7 days? My only thought is that subtracting a week would be better if you need to handle non-gregorian calendars.