# Searching for date backwards with `nextDate(after:matching...` just strangely long in time?

Tags: ios, swift, date

I use `nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)` to search for a date backwards.

I want to search for the 23rd of the month before, but I get a jump to from 2022 to 1995.

Is this a bug or am I just missing something calendar-wise that makes this result actually correct?

```
var calendar: Calendar = .autoupdatingCurrent
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Stockholm")!

let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1666310400.0) // "Oct 21, 2022 at 2:00 AM"
print(date) // "2022-10-21 00:00:00 +0000\n"
calendar.nextDate(after: date, // "Sep 23, 1995 at 12:00 AM" ??
                  matching: DateComponents(day: 23),
                  matchingPolicy: .previousTimePreservingSmallerComponents,
                  direction: .backward)
```

Comment: Very strange bug, the code works fine with the current date and time for me but not with the one in the question. I can't relate it to daylight saving time either.

Comment: I did some more testing, the error occurs for dates between the 1st October to the 23rd October.

Comment: Thanks for verifying. Same here. Yeah, it's not a date that I would suspect acting strange..

Comment: Oh, that's interesting..

Comment: if u add 0 to 20 for the day it works fine. When u add 21 it does not work. : (

Comment: I've now filed this as FB11736238

Comment: This appears to happen if there is a DST change in the month from which the calculation is started. Here is another bug about wrong date calculations in connection with DST: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49266027/1187415. More bug reports: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49202865/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47982214/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR hmm, and only DST moving "back" the back, can't seem to reproduce it in march

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple alternative to accomplish the same thing

```
var previous = calendar.date(bySetting: .day, value: 23, of: date)!
while previous > date {
    previous = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: previous)!
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's a creative workaround! Thanks for the suggestion and investigation!

Comment: I think the problem is also ONLY when the date has to wrap to previous month. Searching for 11 from 10th of October fails to 1995 but from 12th works